# Macro or Loop to conditional formatting

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

I need to repeat shown the conditional formatting to all the rows. There are lot of rows. The conditional icon is based on the first value of the cell and others shows according to it. How to achieve all this in one go.
My data ranging from C2:F792.

Comment: image can be found on 'enter image description here' https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEus5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps...

1. Select the range C2:F2 and press Ctrl+C to copy it.
2. Now select the range C3:F792.
3. Right click on any of the selected cells --> Choose Paste Special --> Select the radio button for Formats and click on OK.

If you want to do this programmatically, you may try something like this...

```
Sub CopyConditionalFormatting()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("C3:F792")
Range("C2:F2").Copy
rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you might even try Conditional Formatting:

[[image: SO4492989 example[1]]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but this is not really what I was expecting. To be more clear on this I will explain it little more. From C2:F2 the icon is based on the value of C2. When D3:F3 the icon is based on the value of D3. similarly for others too. In the method you explained, the icon is always based on the value C2.Thanks